# Can't get mongo.so extension to load after updating PHP to 5.3

Tags: php, mongodb

I had PHP 5.2 with MongoDB installed on Debian Lenny x64 and everything was fine.

After updating PHP to 5.3 (dotdeb) I can't get MongoDB to work, I always get an error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found (...)
```

Everything else works fine, all default modules are working.

My php.ini:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php5/20090626"
extension=mongo.so
```

Mongo.so is in same location as written above.
But when I run `php -m` in console to check loaded modules, "mongo" isn't listed there.

I can't use `dl('mongo.so')` to load module at runtime, because this function was deprecated in PHP 5.3.

May be I should recompile mongo somehow, I just don't know how to do that because I'm not very good in *nix commands.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**
Also may be it's worth saying that before my mongo.so was in `/usr/lib/php5/20060613` and I manually copied it to `"/usr/lib/php5/20090626"` because it seems that after updating my PHP all modules are located there.

Comment: From where did you get the extension module for php 5.2? Did you check if this source also provides a module for php 5.3?

Comment: I just ran a command "sudo pecl install mongo"

Comment: Then you should remove the .so you've copied and try `sudo pecl install mongo` again. The extension module api has changed between php5.2 and php5.3. When php tries to load an extension module both sides have to "present" an api magic key that identifies the api version. If those numbers don't match the module is not loaded/activated.

Comment: Thanks! I did "sudo pecl uninstall mongo" and then "sudo pecl install mongo" again - and now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension module api has changed between php5.2 and php5.3. When php tries to load an extension module both sides have to "present" an api magic key that identifies the api version. If those numbers don't match the module is not loaded/activated.

Try `sudo pecl install mongo` again to get an extension module that fits your new php version.

Comment: Annoyingly you are correct aaron. Does anyone have a work around?

Answer (score 2):

Try re installing mongo & restart service

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongo 
sudo pecl install mongo
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This will install mongo in to newer version

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little time trying to fix this, I am guessing you had a previous mongo install. The way I fixed it was by:

I installed php5-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
cd /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/
sudo rm -rf mongo.ini
```

I then viewed my php.ini and removed `extension=mongo.so`

Then:

```
sudo pecl uninstall mongo 
sudo pecl install mongo
sudo service apache2 restart
```